# Displaying RecordSet in textbox on Form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have created a recordset code that is comparing business id's to grab each customer that's been at this business. I want to pass on this data onto a form through a ubounded textbox or whatver works best for Access. When I have it stored into the unbounded text box in the recordset by using this code in my recordset Forms!Form.Badge = StrBusinesses, it is not showing uniquely on my form per each record/business ID. It shows up the same for each business when I scroll through each record.

How do I get the recordset to show on the form uniquely to each record ?

```
Public Sub OpenRecordset()
    Dim qdf As QueryDef
    Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("QOff2")
    qdf.Parameters(0).Value = [Forms]![Form]![Text10]

    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim StrBusinesses As String

    Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset

    If rs.EOF And rs.BOF Then
        MsgBox ("No businesses exist for this Customer")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        rs.MoveFirst
    End If

    StrBusinesses = ""
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        StrBusinesses = StrBusinesses & rs!Fnam & ", "
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    rs.Close

    StrBusinesses = Left(StrBusinesses, Len(StrBusinesses) - 2)
    Forms!Form.Badge = StrBusinesses

    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

My query sql code:

```
SELECT badgeno, FNAM, filenum
FROM ((INC LEFT JOIN AIO ON INC.NUM = aio.NUM) LEFT JOIN off ON aio.FNUM = off.FNUM) LEFT JOIN all ON aio.AIO_NUM = all.ALGNUM
WHERE (((FILENUM)=[forms]![form].[text10]));
```

I am displaying it on a form by creating an unbounded textbox on my form and named it badge (Forms!Form.Badge). While when I push the run/green play button it updates all my unbounded textboxes in each form, so when I see the next record it says the same thing on the previous record. Also, I want it to show automatically without pushing the green play button in the module.

Comment: Any reason why you would go through VBA? You could easily get what you want by using a Parent and Child Form.

Comment: I was using a dlookup, then realized that couldn't use dlookup for multiple outputs. Right now I have it setup as a subform to show the data, but I was learning recordset vba coding so I just want to be able to complete the code to show these rows. For performance curiousity, would a subform be less quality over creating a vba to show the output @PaulFrancis?

Comment: VBA is a messy/complicated way to achieve what you want with this scenario. The performance hit might be greater as, for every record a new object of the table is instantiated. Having a SubForm would make your life a lot more easier.

Comment: @PaulFrancis, thank you. I guess I will stick to the subform but is there anyway you can help me with listing this in the unbounded textbox just to figure it out?

Comment: Okay could you please update your OP, with the SQL of the Query and also where is this `textbox` placed and how are you calling this code?

Comment: @PaulFrancis, it is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the textbox assignment code like this

```
Me.yourtextboxname.value = StrBusinesses
```

Comment: @rajinikant sharma, when I put in Me.Badge.Value = StrBusinesses = StrBusinesses vs Forms!Form.Badge = StrBusinesses, I get error invalid use of me word.

Comment: here is some reference usage of Me http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

Comment: @rijinikant Sharma, am I supposed to be looking at To refer to a form property, like RecordSource?

Comment: RecordSource here referred is value property of control like form or textbox etc.